# Flutter app running in local device sucessfully but showing Java.runtime.class Error while testing via downloading from google play store

Tags: android, flutter

[image: Screenshot]

Our team has done the app in android studio, and apk file is succesfully running in local device. But when testing and downloading from google play store it is showing java.runtime.class error. Kindly help in sorting the issue.

Comment: Can you share the full error?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sVoy9oWDvko-oBvKyjLdS5SpBUysbT_V?usp=sharing

Comment: Pls find the error images in the drive

Comment: Hi Tomerpacific, could not give the error details as it is extending the number of characters allowed here, so i shared a screenshot of the error, you can check in the drive for which the link was given earlier

Comment: I would suggest editing your question with it.